# write a bootloader for atmega328p

Tags: c, microcontroller, bootloader

I have been searching around the web, but didn't find anything useful telling me how to start.

I have an Atmega328p. I think this is the easiest controller to start with for this kind of things.

I would like to write my own bootloader. Where should I start to write code for?

Comment: You could look at Micronucleus - it is a below 2 kb bootloader for attiny chips that has serial programming over USB. The atmega has significantly more memory, so you can "go to town" on writing a bootloader, besides, I am sure there are at least a few out there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootloader is essentially a bare-metal program that is running on your micro, listening to one or more communication interfaces (Serial, SPI, USB or you name it..) with a specific protocol. Then, on the PC/programmer side there is a "client" software that can some binary (but not limited to) and *send* it using that protocol to the bootloader. Then upon reception the bootloader will store the received data in some known memory location and issue a "jump" (or "branch" or "goto" or whatever) to the start of that data, thus triggering execution of it assuming it is an executable code. So, you bootloader at very minimum should be capable of:

1) Using one of the communication channels

2) Implementing a specific protocol

3) Storing the received executable in some memory

4) Trigger the execution of that code

From here it's you implementation choice.

Comment: But the information (your program) is usually in the form of a hex file, right?
So I would have to story every (hex) byte in a specific manner in my flash memory (for example).
Sorry if this might sound dumb: How do you tell your microcontroller to interpret these stored bytes as executable code? And afterwards execute it?

Comment: The representation is totally your choice. You have just to know how to translate it to an executable code.

Comment: Indeed this "translation process" is what my question in my previous comment was about. What about that translation?

Comment: The final goal is to get some program written and executed on the MCU, right? So this is the only thing that matters. So you can have the program stored on your PC in *any* format your "client" can decode and send. Or it can even be sent as is, but then it will be up to the bootloader to decode it.

Comment: @PrivetDruzia I think the missing link in your understanding is that the "translation process" is actually being carried out by the compiler or assembler. The Hex bytes you are storing are machine code which is the machine language of the processor you are writing a bootloader for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PDF with an in depth discussion/explanation of the steps to write a bootloader for AVR:

http://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/bootloader_faq.pdf

This was the third hit in Google from searching "atmega write bootloader"

Comment: didn't see that oO. Looks very interesting. thx
I suppose it is a whole different process for ARM controllers unfortunately...